# Delayed::Job tasks not executing and don't clear from queue when they do run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, backgroundworker, delayed-job

My Delayed::Jobs are getting queued, but aren't running. When I inspect them in the console there are no errors in the `last_error` field, indicating they haven't been run. I can run them all successfully in the console with `some_job.invoke_job`, but after they run they don't get cleared from the queue as they should (they used to clear after manually invoking them in the console).

I'm running delayed_job (4.0.4) and Rails 4.1.4. This problem seems to have occurred after a gem upgrade.

I've restarted the delayed_job server several times.

Here is a job in the queue:

`#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 725, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2014-10-16 01:52:11", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2014-10-16 01:52:11", updated_at: "2014-10-16 01:52:11">`

How do I get my delayed::jobs to run automatically, and to get cleared from the queue when they are finished running?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you run the **process responsible for processing delayed jobs**. You have two options here:

1. `bin/delayed_job` - runs a daemon which listens to incoming requests.
2. `rake jobs:work` - processes jobs in the foreground.

You mentioned using [`Delayed::Job#invoke_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/73bd1b50e719b336b70fcbb8dc4a37ec9b2f6f35/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb#L77) in console - this method processes the job, but it won't do anything else, that's why your job was not removed from the queue.

For running jobs and then removing successful ones from the queue, you can use [`Delayed::Worker#run`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/73bd1b50e719b336b70fcbb8dc4a37ec9b2f6f35/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L227).

For example:

```
some_job = Delayed::Job.find(job_id)
Delayed::Worker.new.run(some_job)
```